# Mensagem de Aviso com Necessidade de Ação para Prosseguir

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Gostava que me pode-sem explicar como e que se mantém uma mensagem de aviso(Como a do Exemplo) em constante permanência ate que o GPS do SmartPhone seja Ativo !

**Mais Detalhadamente:**

- Estou a fazer uma pagina Web apenas para ser utilizada em SmartPhones ( Não esta programado em Android ).
- A ideia seria manter a mensagem de aviso ate que o utilizador Active no telemóvel a localização (GPS);

[image: ![![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Como se pode ver na Imagem, este pequeno texto esta a aparecer durante um determinado tempo ate que desaparece***

Pretendia que a mensagem de Aviso se mantive-se ate que o GPS fosse ativo !

***A linha de Codigo***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho ali o "Timer", **mas não quero** a funcionar com o tempo ....

Penso que de para fazer isso com angular, não tenho a certeza !

Comment: Poste o seu código como texto, evite usar foto. Recomendo que edite sua pergunta e adicione o código ;)

Comment: Hum, mas o código do que mais em concreto? :)

Comment: O código referente ao problema que você está tentando resolver

Comment: A questão e que não tenho código ... porque o que estou a pedir, e informação/Código para que possa servir para o que eu tenho duvida :)

Comment: Mas então da onde você tirou esse print do código que colocou na questão?

Comment: Mas isso e so HTML e Interface, penso que não e nada nada assim necessario de se colocar, visto que o pedido não tem a haver cm o HTML

Comment: Neste caso, recomendo que você reveja sua questão, pois no modelo que você fez, ela está fora do escopo permitido. Você não pode solicitar um código e esperar que alguém faça isso para você. O objetivo da comunidade é ajudar você a corrigir os erros em seu código atual, ou seja, você deve primeiro tentar fazer o que deseja e, se no meio do caminho tiver dificuldades, ai sim questionar aqui.

Comment: Mas eu não estou a pedir código, estou a pedir uma explicação para eu tentar conseguir fazer !